# PowerShell: String replacement doesn't work every time?

Tags: powershell, replace

I am writing a script to prepare a csv for uploading it into SQL.

I have two almost identical commands (1 and 3) but the first doesn't work, the third one does. There is no error, it just doesn't do what I expect it to do.

I do 3 steps, first I get rid of all the pipes in the source file (this is what does not work), then I read and write the CSV (this gets rid of the different handling of using quotes and not using quotes and it changes the delimiter to pipes). Lastly I get rid of all quotations, since there should be no more pipes other than the delimiters.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Get rid of all pipes
#----------------------------------------------------------
get-content ($csvfile + ".csv") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "|",""} | Set-Content ($csvfile + "2.csv")

# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Make standard CSV but use Pipes as delimiter
#----------------------------------------------------------
Import-csv -path ($csvfile + "2.csv") -Delimiter ',' | Export-CSV -path ($csvfile + " 3.csv") -Delimiter '|'

# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Get rid of all Quotes
#----------------------------------------------------------
get-content ($csvfile + "3.csv") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"',""} | Set-Content ($csvfile + "4.csv")
```

The getting rid-parts are the same. The second one works, it gets rid of all the quotes but the first one does not work, the pipes are still in. I tried different characters but for some reason none works at this position.

What am I missing?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the `|` symbol with `\` like `\|` as below and it will work fine; cause `|` is a special character (command pipe symbol).

```
get-content ($csvfile + ".csv") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "\|",""} | 
Set-Content ($csvfile + "2.csv")
```

So if I have input like `dadad|xcvxvv|sdffgfg` then after the command the output would look like `dadadxcvxvvsdffgfg`

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. I feel bad for not thinking about this earlier.